# Dynamically Allocating a Struct within a Struct

Tags: c, struct, malloc

I am dynamically allocating a struct which has a different struct as a member:

```
struct a {
   // other members
   struct b;
}
```

`struct b` basically holds a pointer to another `struct b`, so think of `struct b` as a linked list.

If I dynamically allocate `struct a`, then that would also make a new `struct b` within it. However, what is the difference between doing that or having `struct a` hold a pointer to `struct b`, and dynamically allocate `struct b` within `struct a`? What is the difference in implementation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you dynamically allocate (malloc) `struct a` as in

```
struct a *temp = (struct a *)malloc(sizeof(struct a));
```

you `malloc` space for a pointer to `struct b` (assuming that's what is in `struct a`) but you don't `malloc` space for `struct b`. That means later you'll have to do

```
temp->b = (struct b *)malloc(sizeof(struct b));
```

before you try and use `struct b`.

If you don't store a pointer to `struct b` but rather `struct b` directly then you'll get the automatic allocation when you define `struct a`.

Answer (score 10):

First, let's get some real definitions in place to make this concrete.

```
struct b {
    int x;
};

struct a_with_b {
    struct b b;
}

struct a_with_b_ptr {
    struct b *bp;
}
```

When you encapsulate a struct, you just need to allocate the outer struct (and since the inner struct is not a pointer, you use `.` to reference members of the innert struct):

```
struct a_with_b *a1 = malloc(sizeof(struct a_with_b));
a1->b.x = 3;
```

But when you encapsulate a pointer, you have to allocate each independently and use `->` when referencing members of the inner struct:

```
struct a_with_b_ptr *a2 = malloc(sizeof(struct a_with_b_ptr));
a1->b = malloc(sizeof(struct b));
a1->b->x = 3;
```

Answer (score 3):

The difference is really equivalent to any other situation where you're comparing "automatic" and "dynamic" allocation.<sup>1</sup>

In terms of a guide as when you should use a pointer member, I would say that you should avoid it unless there's a good reason not to, due to the programmer overhead in dealing with manual memory management (and the bugs that it inevitably leads to).

An example of a good reason would be if you needed your struct `a` to refer to an existing struct `b`.

---

<sub>1. "automatic" is the term used in the C standard for this sort of allocation, because the memory is cleaned up automatically.</sub>