# Struct Hack with Array of Struct Type

Tags: c, struct, malloc

**EDIT - previously posted code mooted because it would not compile**

Say I have the following variant of the struct hack:

```
typedef struct hack *Hack;
struct hack {
    char* value;
    Hack arr[1];
};
```

What exactly should I be mallocing?  Should I be doing something like:

```
malloc(sizeof(struct hack) + sizeof(struct hack)*(numElems-1));
```

which could be shortened to:

```
malloc(sizeof(struct hack) * numElems);
```

Is that correct?

Comment: Can't work, a `struct` cannot contain a member of the same type or an array thereof.

Comment: Your struct [will not compile](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3kyOil$0)

Comment: I had tested it with typedef struct hack *Hack but not with just typedef struct hack Hack, which several of you pointed out correctly will not compile.  However, my question still stands for *Hack.

Comment: Does this help you:  [dynamically-allocating-a-struct-within-a-struct](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864877/dynamically-allocating-a-struct-within-a-struct)?

Comment: I was already familiar with how to do that, but thanks for the link anyway.  I'm still a bit confused in this particular example though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think your first code is right. It is "incomplete element type"

```
typedef struct hack Hack;
struct hack {
    char* value;
    Hack arr[1];
};
```

is equal to:

```
struct hack {
    char* value;
    struct hack arr[1];  /* Here wrong */
};
```

At the wrong point, you try to define an array of `struct hack`, **but:** the definition of `struct hack` is not complete yet. Ohhhh, you modify it.

For your new code, it should be :

```
typedef struct hack *Hack;
struct hack {
    char* value;
    Hack arr;
};
Hack node = malloc(sizeof(struct hack));
node->arr = malloc(sizeof(struct hack) * numElems);
```

In this case, the "node" is a pointer to a single structure hack. And the member "arr" of this entity is another point to an array of structure hack. Otherwise, you could construct your data as a typical linked list.

Update: **pay attention,** all values in the node and `(node->arr)[i]` are not initialized! You should `memset()` them all to zero immediately after `malloc()`. Or make sure to assign a valid value before any use. If you use it before assignment of valid value, it is the best thing to meet a segmentation fault. In a worse case, it costs your days to find out where is wrong.

Comment: That all makes sense - after doing that can I safely get and set (node->arr)[i] for 0<=i<numElems?

Comment: By which I mean set and then get after setting; getting first without setting should segfault right?

Comment: Yes, you could use "(node->arr)[i] for 0<=i<numElems'. But pay ATTENTION, all values in the node and (node->arr)[i] are not initialized! You should memset() them all to zero immediately after malloc(). Or make sure to assign a valid value before any use. If you use it before assignment of valid value, it is the best thing to meet a segment fault. In a worse case, it costs your days to find out where is wrong.